# Save attachment to hard drive

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, attachment, dao

I am trying to code a simple task: retrieving an attachment from Access (2013) database and saving it to disk. At the moment I would like the code to get a first record from recordset and save the attachment to  C:\maptest.pdf

It shows error 3265: Item not found in this collection (yet every record in the database has an attachment).

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim appAcc As New Access.Application
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset2
Dim rsA As DAO.Recordset2
Dim fld As DAO.Field2

Dim dbpath As String
dbpath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\SiteDetails.accdb"

With appAcc
    .OpenCurrentDatabase dbpath
     Set rst = .CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SiteMaps")
     Set rsA = rst.Fields("Map").Value
End With


rsA.Fields("Map").SaveToFile _"C:\maptest.pdf"


AppAcc.Quit
Set appAcc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: read this please: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: what line is this erroring on?

Comment: It was showing error in: rsA.Fields("Map").SaveToFile _"C:\maptest.pdf" but when I changed "Map" to "FileData" it worked fine. It seems that I don't have to reference a column named "Map" but "FileData" (even though FileData does not exist as a column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Map isn't the identifier DAO is using.

Change this line,

```
rsA.Fields("Map").SaveToFile _"C:\maptest.pdf"
```

to,

```
rsA.Fields("FileData").SaveToFile "C:\maptest.pdf"
```

Per [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb258184%28v=office.12%29.aspx),

> The FileData field is reserved internally by the Access database
>   engine to store the binary attachment data.

Update: I posted this before I saw your latest update that you discovered the solution.  To put it briefly, the reason is you're splitting a field into its own, sorta customized, child recordset of file attachments (really nice feature to have in DAO).