# Access: display .vsd from attachments

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, visio

I have an Access table where each item has attached a Visio file (.vsd).

In my Access form, I would like to see the file. I don't care if it is an editable Visio file, a preview or just an image.

I have built a VBA code that let me load the Visio file from a Directory. But I need to **load the file from a table**.

Here my VBA code.

```
Private Sub Carica_Dati()

Dim path As String
path = "C:\Users\VisioFlow_001.vsd"


With Me.VisioObject  ' name of the OLE Object where I want to put the Visio file
    .Class = "Visio.Drawing.11"
    .OLETypeAllowed = acOLELinked
    .SourceDoc = path ' HERE I WANT TO LOAD THE FILE FROM A TABLE OF THE DB
    .Enabled = True
    .Locked = False
    .Action = acOLECreateLink
    .SizeMode = acOLESizeZoom
End With

End Sub
```

Here a preview of the form.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Here a picture to show how the file is attached to the table.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the table contain the *path* to the file, or the *binary contents of the file itself*? If the former, all you need is a `SELECT` query (should be pretty trivial); if the latter... you probably need to extract the data to an actual file on disk, and load it from there.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I have updated the question. Can it help?

Comment: Yeah. So you need to `SELECT` the attachment you need, save it to disk (under `%TEMP%`, probably), and pass its location to `.SourceDoc`

Comment: @Mat'sMug GREAT!!! thanks :) the problem is that I am not able to do that. May you kindly write the main code if it is not a hard work? I really need to solve this problem in order to deliver this document tonight.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I mean just how to save in a temporary directory and how to know the path. Then I guess that I have just to copy the path into `.SourceDoc`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Access, even less with "Attachment"-type data. I presume the Access object model provides an API for that "Save" method...

Comment: @Mat'sMug what do you mean with "save method"?

Comment: That dialog has a Save button. That means the object model probably has some `Attachments` collection containing some `Attachment` items that expose a `Save` or `SaveAs` method - I don't know, do a bit of research, I'm sure you'll find it.

Comment: From a 2-second google search: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23390263/1188513

Comment: There is an ActiveX control in Access called Microsoft Visio Document. I've never used any of the ActiveX controls, no idea if it will do what you want. Otherwise, export the file to external location and open in its native app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since attachment fields in Access aren't very consistent, directly loading them into an OLE object is not an option, unless you're willing to do sophisticated things

Microsofts documentation on attachments can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/attachment-object-access)

My observations on attachments: the binary data field contains one of the following:

- Some characters I can't identify + the file type + the file data appended to it
- Some characters I can't identify + the file type + a compressed version of the file data appended to it

Microsoft, in all it's wisdom, has supplied us with a way to save the original file to the disk, but hasn't supplied us with a way to remove those initial characters and the file type from the actual file data, or an easy way to identify if the file is compressed or not (you can check the file type with the table supplied in the link to check if it should be).

In conclusion, you're probably off best either replacing your attachment field with an OLE object in the database, or writing the attachment files to disk before displaying them.

If you use an OLE object field, and load them in as long binary data (not through the GUI), you can easily achieve the behaviour you seek without writing the file to disk, since the binary data is available without any extra characters.

To write an attachment file to disk:

```
Dim rsForm As DAO.Recordset2
Dim rsFiles As DAO.Recordset2
Set rsForm = Me.Recordset
Set rsFiles = rsForm.Fields("attachment_column").Value
If Not rsFiles.EOF Then
    Dim fileLocation As String
    fileLocation = Environ("TEMP") & rsFiles.Fields("FileName").Value
     rsFiles.Fields("FileData").SaveToFile fileLocation
    'Your existing code to display the OLE object here
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to use the Attachment feature.  Its purpose is different than what you are attempting.

Put the images into their own stand alone folder outside of the database.

In the table that holds the records for your main form - you need a new field which holds the path & image file name.  This is a text field.  (If the path segment is uniform for all one can insert that elsewhere via code rather than store it in this field.)

Then in form design - use the image control.  This control (all controls) have a source property - that will change with each record using that field that holds the path & file name.

Do a bing/google on the topic of changing an image with every record - the set up isn't intuitive necessarily.  Note that older editions did things differently so be sure you get relatively recent advice.

Then when you are using the form and change records - the image will change.

Note after having typed all this.... I have no idea if the visio file type works - I know that jpg and bmp do... so first sanity check a simple fixed image with that file type to see if it works ...